# Extending enum with Flags, interfere the current use

Tags: c#, enums

The system have a plain enum like this,

```
public enum SomeEnum : short
{ 
    Ok = 0,
    Missing = 17,
};
```

This enum are now into a situation where I need to mask some more information into it without change the appearence of the existing enum values. The enum will got some new values,

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeEnum : short
{ 
    Ok = 0,
    Missing = 17,
    Blocking = 18, // Values could be anything
    Low  = 19,     // Values could be anything
};
```

I was afraid there could be problem to the current enum usage. It appears that I'm right, but **I hope i'm proved wrong with your help**. The usage until today are built around `SomeEnum.Ok`. Also tomorrow, but the Ok need additional info. I need to mask the enum values without affect it's current behavior, which could came from any common reference;

```
someEnumVariable.ToString()
(int)someEnumVariable
someVar = SomeEnum.Ok
Enum.Parse(typeOf(SomeEnum), someString)
```

If I flag the enum with

`var test = (SomeEnum.Ok | SomeEnum.Blocking);` 
Both flags can be founded i.e. `test.HasFlags(SomeEnum.Ok)` or `test.HasFlags(SomeEnum.Blocking)` but the enum represents as SomeEnum.Blocking, which aren't possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you need to add the [Flags] attribute?

Comment: To really do bit masking well in enums, you should use [Flags] as kenny said, and your values should typically be individual bits (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc) though you can define combos as well...

Comment: What are the problems you are seeing?  The values you added will not affect usage of Ok or Missing since you didn't change their value.

Comment: I didnt paid attention to Flags attribute due its oviously in the topic (i will edit). Even though there are lot of documentation about omitting flags in .net enum just change the behaivior of "tostring".

Comment: @James. The problem sighted is that the or'ed variable change its appearance. You mention individual bit, is that a problem or just a note? Because an older part of the system refer the enum id to database table indexes.

Comment: @Jonas: The problem is if you OR those two values together you will get a new value that may or may not match.  OK == 0 and Blocking == 18, thus var test = SomeEnum.Ok | SomeEnum.Blocking; gives you the value of 18 (Blocking)

Comment: @james, that makes perfect sense! doh, .Blocking 18 does reduce something on .Ok 0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value of `SomeEnum.OK` is 0, calling `HasFlag(SomeEnum.OK)` will *always* return true. When you mask enums together, the process relies on the fact that the sum of any combination of enum values will be unique. Typically you would set these up starting using values of `2^0`, `2^1`, `2^2`, etc. For example:

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeEnum : short
{ 
    Ok = 1,
    Missing = 2,
    Blocking = 4, // Values could be anything
    Low  = 8,     // Values could be anything
}
```

If you want to mask the values together, you'll have to use the `Flags` attribute. If you can't refactor and change the value of `SomeEnum.OK`, then you may have to rely on passing in a `SomeEnum[]`, rather than a single masked `SomeEnum` value.

**EDIT**
Just a quick note on masking the values together using the enum defined above. Take the following code:

```
var t1 = (int)(SomeEnum.OK | SomeEnum.Missing);       //t1 = 1 + 2 = 3
var t2 = (int)(SomeEnum.Missing | SomeEnum.Blocking); //t2 = 2 + 4 = 6
var t3 = (int)(SomeEnum.OK | SomeEnum.Low);           //t3 = 1 + 8 = 9
var t4 = (int)SomeEnum.OK;                            //t4 = 1
var s1 = (SomeEnum.Ok).ToString();                    //s1 = "Ok"
var s2 = (SomeEnum.Ok | SomeEnum.Missing).ToString(); //s2 = "Ok, Missing"
```

When these items are OR'ed together, .NET just adds the values together to produce a new, unique value that represents the combination of the OR'ed items. Using enum values that are powers of 2 ensures that the combinations will always be unique.

Comment: I think you got right on target. Probably just some unluck,  that bringed me to this :). It should be less job to refactor the .Ok = 0. I check it tomorrow (gmt+1).

Comment: Referring to your edit. That's the point why I also ask about the presence of the enum when standard enum comparations being done. Is (int)varSomeEnum still 1 (in your sample)? Are varSomeEnum.ToString() still 'Ok'? It would take less time in a console test app to test but I already defined the question and im on subway :)

Comment: @Jonas I think enums are just easier to look at than int values for some things. I added a few more examples (note that I'm using .NET 4.0).

Comment: 'var s2'. There we go. A stringify need to return just "Ok" and if you do a 'var s3 = (int)(.Ok ¦ .Missing) you probably get 16? Or like that.. an intify have to return an intact 1. Blocking and Low are special values that only serve as "extra information" to one of the first values (.Ok). They should affect the enum only if they are requested. In principle. They could be hided at the last 2 of the 4 bit of the short (because the first values would fit into a byte size). I hope this make my situation more clear

Comment: I THINK, that if I add i.e. power of 2 on relevant enum value, i can let the origin Ok value remain intact. But not sure if so and how to accomplish it nicely..

Comment: As I thought, I ran into this problem with intifiying and stringify the enums. Also there isn't managable to refactor the code to .Ok = 1 this time. See comment to sq33g below,

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx

I think a quick introduction to binary OR is in order.

| doesn't just let you sneak two integers into one variable. It performs a mathematical operation.

Therefore, *any* value other than 0 OR'ed with 0 will return that value itself.

You will probably encounter further unexpected behavior if you supply flag values that are not a single bit, such as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.

**EDIT**

If you want to build a Flags enum around the existing values, you can do that. Don't use the currently reserved bits 10001 (17) for any other value, and be careful when testing for Ok.

Comment: +1, but it's funny that in the documentation you linked to it states under the Guidelines: "Define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap.", but then in the sample code the enum starts with a value of 0. Am I missing something or is that wrong?

Comment: Microsoft seems to think that all enums should have a 0 value defined, so that an uninitialized value is meaningful. This interferes with how easily people can use the enum, in the case of flags. Take it or leave it.

Comment: And 0 (None) value is typically used in a Flags enum to indicate no flags are set.  0 is always a default value for an uninitialized enum so you should have a flag that represents 0.

Comment: Im in touched with bitwise, binary and / or. What I need is someone skilled that ben into this situation and solved it or already learned the (perhaps) better way :)

Comment: @sq33G I see what you're saying, but it's weird in the example that 0 is Black, not None. The idea of having an uninitialized value have meaning in an enum makes sense though, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thank's. I blinded the fact .Ok was 0. I also stated that there are undoable re-code the value. This Q  was not able to solve, without side-effects managed at this time. I had to create a new SomeEnum variable to put the flags into. Though, this new variable will be prepared for enum-flags use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to accomplish this using a bitflag. This will however likely force you to change your existing flag comparisons.

```
 [FlagsAttribute] 
enum tester
{
    alpha = 1,
    beta = 2,
    gamma = 4,
    reggy=3
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tester t = tester.alpha | tester.beta;
        if (t == tester.alpha)
            Console.WriteLine("alpha only");
        if ((t & tester.alpha) != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("alpha");
        if ((t & tester.beta) != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("beta");
        if ((t & tester.gamma) != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("gamma");
        if (t == (tester.beta | tester.alpha))
            Console.WriteLine("alphabeta");

        //this will produce alpha, beta, alphabeta
```

Comment: When you test, it is useful to test against the original value in case the value is a combo of flags: if ((t & tester.alpha) == tester.alpha)

Comment: Also, .NET 4.0 added `HasFlag()` method:  `if (t.HasFlag(tester.gamma))`

Comment: The value for `reggy` should be 8, not 3, no?

Comment: Thanks. It looks okey, will going through it when back to work. There are no problem with 'change existing comparstions' as long I dont have to Begin Comparations, where there are no comparations today. This is the first place to begin comparation.

Comment: @rsbarro yeah, I was going to add an example where if you didn't use powers of two that it wouldn't function, but I didn't get to it.